# How can I play a .mkv video with subtitles on the raspberry pi 3b?

Tags: pi-3b+, video

How can I play a .mkv video with subtitles on the raspberry pi 3b?
using osmc or anything else.

Also

Can I add or use external fonts?

I am new to this section so excuse me.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi :-) Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use VLC to display subtitles. In the PiXEL desktop environment, go to `Sound and Video > VLC Media Player` from the applications menu. In VLC open the video file from `Media > Open File` and the subtitle file from `Subtitle > Add Subtitle File`. One can change the default subtitle font in `Tools > Preferences > Subtitles / OSD > Subtitle effects > Font`.